# Pushing local git repository from Matlab fails: You can't push to git://github.com/user/repo.git use https://github.com/user/repo.git

Tags: git, matlab, github

I recently started using GitHub because I want to share some Matlab code with a coworker. However, I cannot seem to get the Git integration to push my changes to the online repository.
I have tried using the SVN integration with https://github.com/user/repo.git and the Git integration with git://github.com/user/repo.git with no success.

Every time I select Push from the Source Control menu I get the following error message:
git://github.com/user/repo.git: You can't push to git://github.com/user/repo.git Use https://github.com/user/repo.git

Switching to SVN and using https://github.com/user/repo.git leads to a different error (https://github.com/user/repo.git: cannot open git-upload-pack).

I am very much at the end of every path I could find. Has anyone had similar issues? I am working on a MacBook Pro using Matlab 2016b.

Thank you.

Comment: Seem's like you don't have right to push. Does your username and email int `git config` match thoses on github ? Are you the owner of the repo ?

Comment: Why are you using SVN integration? It's a Git repo.

Comment: @PTRK Thanks, yes it's my repository. I just updated username and email and I still get the same error that I can't push with git:// and should use https://

Comment: @SamRoberts I want to use Git source control. I tried out SVN because Matlab kept telling me to use the https link, which only works in SVN

Comment: I don't think that's true. You can typically use an https link with Git.

Comment: Github supports https : [link](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what fixed it:

(1) Set up a local Git repository (either through Matlab by going to Source Control > Manage files, and selecting Git integration OR using command line syntax)
The address used for this is either git://github.com/username/repository.git (through Matlab) OR https://github.com/username/repository.git (through terminal)

(2) Setup an SSH key for your system as described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/263934-every-time-i-push-to-the-remote-github-repository-i-have-to-re-input-my-username-and-password-is-t#answer_206317)

(3) If not done so already during step 2, change the Git repository origin to the SSH [address](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/) (git@github.com:username/repository) using
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repository.git